# Action script 3 regular expression matching

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I currently have the following action script regular expression (cut down for readability):

```
private var _emoticonRegEx:RegExp = /(:[)|\(thumbsup\)|<3|O_O)/g;
```

This is used to match strings in a chat tool and replace with various emoticons.
For example if a user enters <3 it is replace with a heart emoticon.

All string are matched except "O_O" regardless of its positioning in the regexp string.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the string 'O_O' specifically is not matched?

Comment: I think you might have an extra `)` at the end.

Comment: You should escape characters for clarity. I'm surprised it's even working in the first place. To me, it seems like you meant to have this regex: `(:\[|\(thumbsup\)|<3|O_O)` to match `:[`, `(thumbsup)`, `<3` and `O_O`.

Comment: There a many great reasons why cell/mobile phones are dropping support for flash. Let us all work towards this glorious horizon and not answer Flash related questions :)) javascript is far from fantastic but flash is an obnoxious contorsion of javascript that i personally cant stand! I for one will stand against flash till the bitter end ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is what i was after:

```
/(:\[|\(thumbsup\)|<3|O_O)/g;
```

Needed to remove the closing bracket from the first :[ and escape the [ (Thanks Jerry)

Answer (score 0):

```
\:\[\)|\(thumbsup\)|<3|O_O.
```

You forgot screening operation for symbols: `[,),:.`